# Firebase authentication not-supported-in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm tried to make firebase in nodejs as firebase documentation the email&password auth it's working good , but when I use a provider auth like google it's show me this message

> auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

this is my code

```
router.get('/signin/google', (req,res,next)=>{
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) =>{
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(token,user)

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

})

please bring your attention I have the server like http://localhost:3000 and call the api http://localhost:3000/signin/google from browser and from angular server in both of case give me the same message

Comment: i think this question is duplicated, try this : 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681352/web-google-authentication-with-firebase

Comment: @android !! how I open the route page from browser as the server I use nodejs as a server ?

Comment: I don't really get your questions. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @android  in topic that you mentioned it , the answer is run the page inside server/Apache , right !! currently i'm run my page with nodejs server !! so I have did this answer before but still not working !

Comment: @francisco-mateo

Comment: I can't understand why somebody close this question. It's clearly not replied in that thread.